# Layout elements duplicated on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been developing a simple android application.

It worked fine on several virtual devices and on HTC One S, but when I started it on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 with Android 4.0.4 all the elements on the layout was duplicated. Its visible with the virtual keyboard and without it.

Here is the Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/password_label"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:id="@+id/password_view" />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ok_label"
    android:id="@+id/password_confirm"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="checkPassword" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Activity source code:

```
public class PasswordActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_password);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.password_confirm);

    if (SharedPreferencesHandler.isPreferenceSet(this, SharedPreferencesHandler.PreferenceKey.PASSWORD_PREFERENCE_KEY)) {
        button.setText(R.string.ok_label);
    } else {
        button.setText(R.string.save_label);
    }

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_view);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                checkPassword();
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
}
//some utility methods
}
```

Here is a screenshot of that bug:

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to have more layout folders in the res folder ?

Comment: No, only one layout folder, no size or orientation suffixes.